# modal inside an ng-repeat directive causes crash

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, datepicker

i am trying to put inside a table abutton that will open a modal.
but no matter which button i click it seems that it tries to open it many times.
i have put the openModal and closeModal inside the main controller.
i believe the problem might be because i am using it inside an ng-repeat?
but in any case i do not know what is going wrong. what am i doing wrong?
i am using this modal:

```
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal
```

the html code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4" ng-repeat="court in courts"> 
      <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
        <caption><h4>court {{court.records[0].id}}<h4></caption>
        <tr>
          <th style='text-align:center'>Hour</th>
          <th style='text-align:center'>Player 1</th>
          <th style='text-align:center'>Player 2</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="record in court.records">
          <td width="50" >{{record.hour}}</td>
          <td ng-style="user1Payed(record)" style='text-align:center'>{{record.u1_first}} {{record.u1_last}}</td>
          <td ng-style="user2Payed(record)" style='text-align:center'>{{record.u2_first}} {{record.u2_last}}</td>
          <td> <!-- options button -->
            <button class="btn" ng-click="openModal()">Open me!</button>
            <div modal="shouldBeOpen" close="closeModal()" options="opts">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning cancel" ng-click="closeModal()">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
          </td> <!-- options button end -->
        </tr> 
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the controller code:

```
function CourtsController($scope, $window, $http, CourtsService, $timeout) { 
  $scope.openModal = function () {
    $scope.shouldBeOpen = true;
  };

  $scope.closeModal = function () {
    $scope.closeMsg = 'I was closed at: ' + new Date();
    $scope.shouldBeOpen = false;
  };

 $scope.items = [
            "Guest Payment",
            "Member Payment",
            "League (no payment)",
            "no Payment"
          ];

  $scope.opts = {
    backdropFade: true,
    dialogFade:true
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move you modal div of the `ng-repeat` and set $scope variable according your `openModal()`.